# Tension in the same string between different masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

In the given diagram:

[image: Masses and pulley]

If the string in the entire system is the same and is assumed to be massless, then why is the tension in the string between objects $M_1$ and $M_2$ different from the tension in the string between objects $M_2$ and $M_3$?
$M_2$ and $M_3$ have equal masses and $M_1$ is assumed to be moving downwards with a uniform velocity.

I am assuming the reason is because , even though the string is the same yet the force by which $M_1$ pulls onto $M_2$ is not the same as the force by which $M_2$ pulls onto $M_3$ because the weights of $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not equal. Is this right?

Comment: Think of the two strings as two arms, where one arm carries the light box $M_1$ and the other carries the heavier box $M_2$. Naturally the tension to hold the heavier box is larger.

Comment: Edited to get the picture inline.

Comment: *"$M_1$ is assumed to be moving downwards with a uniform velocity."* Why is this assumed? If there's no friction and $M_1$ is large enough there will be acceleration.

Comment: @Gert it was given in the question that I was supposed to solve. Thanks for editing.

Comment: @Steeven but in a massless string , isn’t the tension the same throughout the string ?

Comment: @Amanda: you really need to work out all the forces acting on the masses and assume there's zero net force on each of them.

Comment: @Gert exactly what I was trying to do , however that is where I faced a problem on whether I should be taking two different tensions as the weights of the objects were different or the same tension as the string is the same throughout.

Comment: @Gert Friction does exist on the entire surface and the coefficient of kinetic friction is $0.25$

Comment: I see two independent strings, the one between M1 and M2, and another between M2 and M3.  When you write "the string in the entire system is the same", what do you mean?

Comment: @Alfred actually I Didn’t quite understand how can there be two different strings . It looks like the entire system moves along a single string. How did you reason that ?

Comment: @Amanda, I don't know what you mean by "moves along a single string".  The masses don't move along the string as I understand these kinds of problems.  That is, the end of a string is *attached* to a mass so one end of string 1 is attached to M1 and the other end of string 1 is attached to M2.

Comment: @Alfred sorry ,I framed it wrong . I do know that the string moves and not the masses . So you mean to say that the same string is divided into different parts that are attached to different masses and the tension in each part of a string depends on the masses it is attached to ?

Comment: Yes, the tension throughout a massless string is constant. But you have two strings here. One on either side of $M_2$. In the same way that you have two arms, one in other side of your body. Two strings can have different tensions

Comment: @Steeven ohh ! Now I realise where I made a mistake. Thanks for explaining !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain why, first consider why IS the tension same throughout the same string. 
(Also the string is considered massless, the assumption is trivial unless mentioned otherwise)

Now, let's consider an element in the string and let's say that the tension on either side of it is $T_1$ and $T_2$.
Now recall Newton's second law which states that summation of all external forces on the body is equal to its mass times its acceleration.
Hence we write that $T_2 - T_1 = m•a$.
As mass of string is zero the mass of each element is also zero. Hence,we get
$T_2-T_1 =0$ or $T_1 = T_2$ proving that the tensions are equal in a massless string. This equality of tensions can only happen if the mass of the body (under analysis) is zero. Hence, as the block has mass the tensions will be different. 
Also, question specific: the block is under influence of gravity also which must be taken account.(Although the acceleration is zero it's mass isn't).

Comment: Ohhh ! I get it now ! Thank you very much for the explanation !